# adding one line of code to PHP file prevents uploading to server

Tags: php, apache, server

Here's a problem I simply cannot figure out. I have some really simply code in a larger PHP file. I could not upload this file to our customers server - it would upload via FTP and immediately disappear again. I tried manually creating the file and pasting the code, then I get a 500 Internal Server Error. All other files in the project uploaded fine. So I started removing bits of this code and tried uploading, and if I remove the line

```
$temp_sub = '(';
```

then it uploads. If I add that like back in again, it will not! If I comment out that line with // it will not. If I totally delete that line and re-write it the same way it will not. If I change the $temp_sub name to something else it will not...
Right now I have NO idea what could cause this! Any ideas anyone?

Thanks for your help :)

```
private function replace_table_arguments2($in_table1,$in_table2,$in_id1,$in_id2,$in_arguments,$in_query){
    // replace table arguments for col in linked table / $in_table1=original table, $in_table2=new table to join, $in_id1=id to connect the 2 tables, $in_in2=id for where arguments

    // get highest existing join
    $join_count = 0;
    while (strstr($in_query,' t'.($join_count+1).' ')){
        $join_count ++;
    }

    $return_join = '';
    $return_where = '';
    $in_list = explode('|',$in_arguments);
    foreach ($in_list as $value1){
        if ($value1){
            $temp_sub = '(';
            if (substr($value1,0,1) !== '.'){
                $join_count ++;
                $return_join .= 'inner join '.$in_table2.' t'.$join_count.' on t'.$join_count.'.'.$in_id1.'='.$in_table1.'.'.$in_id1.' ';
                $temp_sub .= 't'.$join_count.'.'.$in_id2.'="'.$value2.'" and ';
            }
            $temp_sub_list = explode(',',$value1);
            foreach ($temp_sub_list as $value2){
                if ($value2){
                    if (substr($value2,0,1) == '.') $value2 = substr($value2,1);
                    if (substr($value1,0,1) == '.'){
                        $join_count ++;
                        $return_join .= 'inner join '.$in_table2.' t'.$join_count.' on t'.$join_count.'.'.$in_id1.'='.$in_table1.'.'.$in_id1.' ';
                        $temp_sub .= 't'.$join_count.'.'.$in_id2.'="'.$value2.'" and ';
                    }
                    else{
                        $temp_sub .= 't'.$join_count.'.'.$in_id2.'="'.$value2.'" or ';
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($temp_sub == '(') $temp_sub = '';
            elseif (substr($temp_sub,-5) == ' and ') $temp_sub = substr($temp_sub,0,-5).')';
            elseif (substr($temp_sub,-4) == ' or ') $temp_sub = substr($temp_sub,0,-4).')';
        }
        if ($temp_sub) $return_where .= $temp_sub . ' and ';
    }

    if (substr($return_where,-5) == ' and ') $return_where = substr($return_where,0,-5);
    if ($return_where) $return_where = ' ('.$return_where.') ';

    return array($return_join,$return_where);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, problem solved. I changed php.ini to

```
asp_tags = Off
```

and it's loading fine now. It's actually still not letting me upload the file with FTP, but I created an empty file on the web hosters file manager, pasted the contents and renamed it to the PHP file so it's working.

Lizardx I think you're right: just a badly configured server :)

Update: everything worked for 24 hours then the website started throwing errors again. The FontAwesome directory had disappeared and it won't let me upload it (FileZilla says "Could not start upload"). PHP session_start is giving an error "open failed - no such file or directory". My guess is that it's a permission error on the server, the web host (iPage) is looking into it now. The exact same PHP files are working perfectly on many other systems, so I think we can conclude that it is a server config error.

Comment: I assume you are correctly beginning each php block with: <?php and not <? The file not uploading is strange, and filezilla is certainly not the issue. Note that in filezilla they have a very good status panel that shows the exact server responses to each upload/connect attempt, try it again and show the server response data on the rejected attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$temp_sub='('; // note: removing whitespace around =
$temp_sub="(";
$temp_data="(";
$temp_data='(';
```

and see if it works then. Are you sure the file is uploading, ie, does your ftp client show success/error/status messages?

If it's uploading, I'd guess something it making it unreadable (ie, unix permissions: 000 noread/nowrite, unviewable, but actually present.

To verify this ssh into the system and check the file permissions with

```
 ls -l # run inside directory where file should be
```

This type of aberration is strange however, as you know by now, and usually I find such bizarre events to be caused by bad hosters with badly setup servers, which then institute bad security measures to try to get around all the other bad things they do.

```
$temp_sub == '('
```

note that if that line is working, something is triggering some pattern somewhere is my guess, maybe some security thing on the server hard to know, and that pattern is looking for = '(';

Also try Filezilla to make sure it's not something in your ftp client configurations, which is doubtful but you never know.

Comment: thanks for the helpful reply. And yes $temp_sub="("; worked. But when I start adding more of the code back in (I took lots out to find the error) it's now complaining about ' <%> ' saying "unexpected >". I tried changing all single quotes to double but it's giving errors on other lines. So I think you're right, it's a badly setup server. If you have any other ideas I'd love to hear, otherwise I'm waiting for the web hoster now....

Comment: just to add: yes I'm using Filezilla

Comment: Changing to " should not be required, if it is, something is seriously wrong, As I noted below, you are using <?php to start each php code block, correct? And not <?.  If you are correctly starting each code block with <?php then you have a pretty strangely setup server for sure. $temp_sub="("; working suggests some very badly done attempt at security, since any actual syntax issues would only trigger on script execution, not on upload.